# HTTP request with C++

Tags: c++, networking, visual-studio, http

I need to send an HTTP request to the server (www.google.com) and get a response. All this I implement in C ++, and I need a library of minimum size. I tried connecting curl, cpr in Visual Studio, but not successfully. P.S. I'm new to C ++. Thank you everyone :D

Comment: boost c++ library.